# Check if global variable value has changed in last N seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some Javascript that checks if the value of a global variable has changed in the last 10 seconds. My first idea is to use `setTimeout` as follows:

```
var glob = 0;   //global variable which the user can change by clicking a button

//the following code is my attempt to check if glob has changed values in a 10-second period
var tmp_glob = glob;

setTimeout(function(){
    if(tmp_glob == glob){
        console.log("The value hasn't changed.");
    }
}, 10000);
```

My logic is that, after 10 seconds pass, Javascript will check whether `glob` and `tmp_glob` are still the same and, if they are, that means `glob` hasn't changed since `tmp_glob` was initiated. However, this always returns true, even if I change `glob` from the client. I am 100% sure that `glob` is being changed. So why doesn't my code work? Alternatively, can anyone offer a better solution for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: You probably wanted `setInterval` not `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` is only going to run *once*, so unless you change your variable in that first 10 seconds, you will miss it.

Comment: where/how are you changing the value of `glob`?

Comment: use: `window.setInterval(function(){if(tmp_glob == glob){console.log("The valuehasn't changed.");}}, 10000);`

Comment: @MattBurland No, I want `setTimeout`. It only needs to run once after a certain event. Ten seconds later, we check if it's changed, and that's it.

Comment: @agconti Please see my response to Matt, I only need to check the first 10 seconds, not do it every 10 seconds. `glob` does change in the first 10 seconds.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/dChKv/ Your code works as-is.

Comment: @jovan: Well, if "glob does change in the first 10 seconds" then what's the problem? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Are you certain 10 seconds is long enough to witness the change? Is `tmp_glob` also being altered? Something like `glob = tmp_glob = 1` would be capable of defeating the detection.

Comment: @MattBurland The problem, as stated above, is that the check for whether it's changed always returns false.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I think now that `tmp_glob` may also be being altered and that's the root of the problem.

Comment: @jovan if it has changed, that statement is incorrect. see my fiddle. You most likely have a timing/logic problem instead of an issue specific to the code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine, but it's pretty bad practice and your problem may be in your `tmp_glob` getting overwritten. One way to make this more robust would be to enclose your `setTimeout` in a function that owns the `tmp_glob` variable:

```
function watchglob() {
    var tmp_glob = glob;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (tmp_glob == glob) {
            console.log("The value hasn't changed.");
        } else {
            console.log("The value has changed");
            tmp_glob = glob;
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Now when you want to start monitoring you just call:

```
watchglob();
```

But you won't be able to overwrite `tmp_glob` externally.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/aAn9J/2/

You could use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) it you want to avoid defining a named function for this:

```
(function() {
    var tmp_glob = glob;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (tmp_glob == glob) {
            console.log("The value hasn't changed.");
        } else {
            console.log("The value has changed");
            tmp_glob = glob;
        }
    }, 10000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run it in the console, it works for me. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

You can see that the first time I run it, glob has not changed, so it outputs that it hasn't. The second time I run it, I change glob, so it hits the else statement.

Comment: Yes, I see now that my problem may lie in overlapping calls as the client may fire off multiple requests and overwrite `tmp_glob` in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You were asking about alternatives. In my opinion, **you can't say that you are 100% sure of any user acton**. What if he changes the value in 9.9999s and your script treats it as > 10s?

To me, it's better to pair function with an event instead of using interval/timeout. If user can change the variable by clicking, it's better to simply check if newValue (from the HTML content) is different than your variable.

In my example, I assume that you have HTML form, but you can fire that method even on onClick event.

```
var glob = 0;

var setGlobal = function() {
  var value = parseInt(document.form.global.value); //value from document

  if (value !== glob) {
      alert('New value is different'); //if value is different, do what you want
  }

  glob = value; //oh, and remember to assign the new value :)
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4Yx5/1/